# Firebase for Android, How can I loop through a child (for each child = x do y)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is what my test looks like:

[image]

I won't use the fields above, it's just a dummy. But I would like to go through all the children on "users" and for each email return a:

```
System.out.println(emailString);
```

The only way I found of listing an object is using firebaseAdapter, is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Did you mean [`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java)? .What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The easiest way is with a ValueEventListener.

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        System.out.println(user.email);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

The `User` class can be defined like this:

```
class User {
  private String email;
  private String userId;
  private String username;
  // getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: Hi, this code works fine, thank you. However, the last e-mail repeats 2 times for some reason.

Comment: Never mind, fixed it. Now I need to figure out how to execute a code *after* that loop, every code I type executes *before* it.

Comment: What is User here?

Comment: **_User_** is the model class

Comment: @Rosenberg That is because ValueEventListener is asynchronous.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck on the User model part, can you please help me on how I should structure it ?

Comment: Is ValueEventListener the only way to do it? I want to get the current state of the database. I don't care if the database is modified by anyone else.

Comment: This is not a good answer, User.class is not referenced and therefore makes this answer incomplete and bad

Answer (score 8):

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot item_snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

      Log.d("item id ",item_snapshot.child("item_id").getValue().toString());
      Log.d("item desc",item_snapshot.child("item_desc").getValue().toString());
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Genius! fixed my problem

Comment: This is great if you don't want to use a model class... my primitive mind finds unnecessary model class like heavy weights around the neck... my primitive mind i said

Answer (score 4):

Let say you have a reference to the node *users*, you can iterate through the nodes as follows:

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                // Do magic here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
    });
```

Note that the `DataSnapshot child` inside the for loop will have the UIDs as key, not *users*.

Comment: Im curious but isnt this bad? I mean here it is looping `for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren() )` through all users, so if we have 100 users its gonna take so much time to load. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: My suggestion would be either to limit the number of users downloaded via [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query), or you can use a [ChildEventListener](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/ChildEventListener.html) for better multithreading

Answer (score 1):

Use Iterator to iterate through dataSnapshot

```
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> items = snapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            int counter = 0;
            while (items.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot item = items.next();
                Log.i("Result", "email" + item.child("email").getValue().toString());
                Log.i("Result", "User ID" + item.child("userId").getValue().toString());
                Log.i("Result", "User Name" + item.child("username").getValue().toString());
            }
        }
```

Iterator will iterate through all child elements of users and with items.next() you can access child of users's child

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering too late, But I have to

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                      String user = snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                        System.out.println(user);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

This program will print all user Emails

i expect output

```
my@email.com
jonathanwells@email.com
freddyreich@email.com
```

Comment: How this is different than other answers? This is copy paste of @rubenlop88 answer with one changed line. This should be a comment.

Comment: @Emil Sierzega i should post only onDataChange() method.