# Iterate through each item and check item's value in an array Java

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have this code in java which pulls data from Firebase:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            FirebaseData ShiftMap = child.getValue(FirebaseData.class);
       }

}
```

The Model class Firebase Data is:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class FirebaseData {

public String Operator;
public double Ora00;
public double Ora01;
public double Ora02;
public double Ora03;

public FirebaseData() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class)
    }

    public FirebaseData(String operator, double ora00, double ora01, double ora02, double ora03)
    {
       this.Operator = operator;
       this.Ora00 = ora00;
       this.Ora01 = ora01;
       this.Ora02 = ora02;
       this.Ora03 = ora03;
    }
}
```

How can i iterate through each item to check their value.

right now im doing in this way but i think that it's not the right way:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        FirebaseData ShiftMap = child.getValue(FirebaseData.class);

if (!Map.Operator.isEmpty())
                {
                    if (ShiftMap .Ora00 == 0)
                    {
                        //Do Something
                    }
                    else if (ShiftMap .Ora00 == 0.5)
                    {
                        //Do Something
                    }
                    else if (ShiftMap .Ora00 == 1)
                    {
                        //Do Something
                    }

}
```

**EDIT**

As @AlexMamo requested here is database structure:

```
[
{       
    "Operator": "someone",
    "Ora00": 0,
    "Ora01": 0,
    "Ora02": 0,
    "Ora03": 0,        
},
{        
    "Operator": "someone",
    "Ora00": 0,
    "Ora01": 0,
    "Ora02": 0,
    "Ora03": 0,        
}
]
```

Comment: i hope it helps [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366717/firebase-for-android-how-can-i-loop-through-a-child-for-each-child-x-do-y)

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i edited my question, but if you need it in json i can provide it.

Comment: And how is your `myRef` defined?

Comment: ````FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Map/Data/2017-04-06");````

Comment: @WigunaR it's is the same thing i'm doing. My problem is that i want to look into items value if it is 0, 0.5 or 1. in database i have 5 items and i want to check if they have this values (0, 0.5 or 1). Right now i'm doing:     ````if (ShiftMap .Ora00 == 0)````. But i'm trying to find something like: ````if (ShiftMap .GetItemsValue() == 0)````, i dont know if it's possible

Comment: If the code you have works, then it's not wrong.  Does it not work the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson the code is working even in this way, but i was thinking if i could find something better.